# Reverse of a termspace forcing fact

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing

Suppose $\kappa$ is an inaccessible cardinal.  Consider the termspace forcing for adding a Cohen subset of $\kappa$ after $\mathbb P= Col(\omega,<\kappa)$. Members are Levy names for countable partial functions from $\kappa$ to 2, ordered by $\tau \leq \sigma$ iff $1 \Vdash \tau \leq \sigma$.  Call this $T(\mathbb P, Add(\kappa))$.

It is well known that the identity map is a projection from $\mathbb P \times T(\mathbb P, Add(\kappa))$ to the iteration $\mathbb P *  \dot Add(\kappa)$.  Furthermore in this situation it is not hard to show that $T(\mathbb P, Add(\kappa)) \cong Add(\kappa)$. So if $G \times H$ is $\mathbb P \times Add(\kappa)$-generic, then in the extension there is $I$ such that $G * \dot I$ is $\mathbb P *  \dot Add(\kappa)$-generic.

My question is what about the opposite. In $V[G* \dot I]$ is there an $Add(\kappa)^V$-generic?

Comment: Monroe, unless I have misunderstood, the actual question is not about termspace forcing, although it was evidently motivated by termspace forcing. Right?

Comment: For those like me who have not heard of termspace forcing, see https://mihahabic.wordpress.com/tag/termspace-forcing/

Comment: It is also known as term forcing, and appears to have been discovered/rediscovered many times in forcing.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins-- right. I will adjust the title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is no. Forcing with
$\mathbb{P}*\dot{\text{Add}}(\kappa,1)$ adds no fresh subsets to
$\kappa$, that is, a new subset of $\kappa$ all of whose initial
segments are in $V$. Thus, it cannot add a $V$-generic filter for
$\text{Add}(\kappa,1)^V$.

To see this, note that $\mathbb{P}$ is productively $\kappa$-c.c.,
meaning that $\mathbb{P}\times\mathbb{P}$ is $\kappa$-c.c., since
$\mathbb{P}$ remains $\kappa$-c.c. after forcing with
$\mathbb{P}$, since in the extension it amounts to
$\text{Add}(\omega,\kappa)$, which is c.c.c. there.

It now follows from Spencer Unger's improved version of my lemma
on [the approximation and cover properties](http://jdh.hamkins.org/approximation-and-cover-properties/), which go back to results implicit in 
Mitchell's dissertation. Specifically, it follows from lemma 1.3
in his paper [Spencer Unger, FRAGILITY
AND INDESTRUCTIBILITY II](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~sunger/Indestructible2.pdf) that $\mathbb{P}*\dot{\text{Add}}(\kappa,1)$ has
the $\kappa$-approximation property, meaning this forcing adds no
new sets of ordinals all of whose small approximations are in the
ground model. Thus, it can add no $V$-generic subsets of $\kappa$
using $\text{Add}(\kappa,1)^V$.

Comment: In the paper "[THE APPROXIMATION PROPERTY AND THE CHAIN CONDITION](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/1895-10.pdf)" a generalization of Unger's result is presented. See Lemma 1.5 there.